# $("").click(function(){ Allow of click of images in a loop

Tags: php, html

I am trying to allow user to click on the picture that is displayed on the website, currently, the picture is pull out from a database and is on a loop. If i set a id, user can only click on the first pic that is shown, is there anyway for the `$("#HELP").click(function(){` to allow me to have one code but allow all the pic to be click ?

```
<div id = 'HotelContentsmallpic'>
<?php 
$cols=4;        // Here we define the number of columns
    echo "<table>"; // The container table with $cols columns
    do{
        echo "<tr>";
        for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++){   // All the rows will have $cols columns even if
                                    // the records are less than $cols
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
            if($row){
                $img = $row['IMG'];
                $cat = $row['Category'];
 ?>
        <td> 
            <table>
                <tr align="top">
                    <td><img id = "HELP" src="images/Hotel/<?php echo $img ?>.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></td> 
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>  <!-- Create gap between columns -->
                </tr>
           </table>
        </td>
<?php
            }
            else{
                echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; //If there are no more records at the end, add a blank column
            }
        ?>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){                         
        $("#HELP").click(function(){
       window.location='hotels.php?Category=<?php echo $cat ?>&Pic=<?php echo $img ?>';
                });
            });
        </script> 
        <?php
        }
    } while($row);
    echo "</table>";
 ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change two things:

**In HTML use img `tag` like that:**

```
<img onclick="redirect_url('<?=$cat?>','<?=$img?>')" src="images/Hotel/<?=$img?>.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
```

**And in Javascript use this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect_url(cat,img)
{
    window.location='hotels.php?Category='+cat+'&Pic='+img+'';
}
</script>
```

In this solution, no need to use `#HELP` id in this.

Comment: YESSSS IT WORKS THANKS ^^ your a life savior

Comment: mention not , now chose the best answer and mark as accepted because this will help for others who facing this issue to. @Melvin

Answer (score 0):

You are using the the ID attribute, in this case you should use the class attribute since there are multiple elements of the type "HELP". So basically #HELP to .HELP and id="HELP" to class="HELP"